# [GADObjectPrivate changeState:]: and don't want to add -objC , -all_load

Tags: objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk, unrecognized-selector

I am having the error and it is AdMob crashes with [GADObjectPrivate changeState:]: unrecognized selector.
I know I need to add -objC but if I add, the following consequences occur.

Consequence
I am using Parse SDK and now I don't need to add facebook SDK (because I don't use -objC).
If I add facebook SDK, there are many other problems occur and it might need not to support iphone 3gs, 4,etc.

As a result, I need to know a way to solve this problem without adding -objC and also -all_load. I would like to know how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out a way to do.

Instead of using -objC, I can set to the required library only by using this.

```
-force_load <library file name>
```

So, -objC isn't required.